# Retrofit returns response.body as null for code 302

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, httpresponse, http-status-code-302

I am calling a web service with GET method from Android client, which returns null response if the `response code is 302`. I am using `Retrofit` lib for network handling. Although I get the response if response code is 200.

With the same call in postman or browser, I get the response even if the response code is 302.

Is there any special handling required for Retrofit to return the actual response instead of null?

Comment: Show your code, what do you use for json serialization?

Comment: Got anything @mayur...??